# Return value from Mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have example with mutex. `CurrentValue` - member of `Class`

```
int Class::NextValue()
{
   mutex.lock();
   ++CurrentValue;
   ++CurrentValue;
   int localValue = CurrentValue;
   mutex.unlock();
   return localValue;
}
```

I don't understand why is used `localValue`. Next code will not work properly?

```
   ...
   mutex.unlock();
   return CurrentValue;
```

In case when `return` is not atomic `CurrentValue` can change during copy constructor. But in the first code example can be the same with `localValue` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CurrentValue` could be changed by another thread between the call to unlock and the function return. But what you really need is a scope guard for the mutex.

C++11:

```
int Class::NextValue()
{
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
   ++CurrentValue;
   ++CurrentValue;
   return CurrentValue;
} // mutex unlocked on exiting this scope.
```

Comment: But `localValue` could change too between the unlock and the return? Yes, I know about guards. Thanks

Comment: @PulsatingAmbience `localValue` is local to the function, so if another thread calls `NextValue`, it will see a different `localValue`. So there's no race condition.

Comment: @PulsatingAmbience yes, exactly!

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything. I did not realize it because in book was written that all threads share all memory. I thought they share call Stack too

Comment: Nope - every thread has its own stack.  That is almost the definition of a thread.  Threads can easily share data.  Threads can easily share code.  Threads never share stack.

Comment: @PulsatingAmbience they share the same virtual memory address space, which is why they can refer to the same data. But they get their own call stack.

Comment: @PulsatingAmbience Having read many books/sites re. threading, I suspect I know why you missed it - most threading 'tutorials' are so apallingly bad, or actually wrong, that it is difficult to find words to express the level of suckness.  Even a black hole would not suck so much.

Comment: Well you also forgot to apply the fundamental principle of _local variables_.

Comment: @MartinJames "threads never share stack" - well, they don't share _the_ stack (_qualitate qua_) but it is perfectly possible that threads share objects allocated on one of those stacks (e.g. a thread holding a reference to a local variable from `main()`. I wouldn't _recommend_ that, but it is not too far-fetched)

Comment: @sehe - sure, if you want to signal the data to, or make the data accessible from, another thread, then fine, as long as you do it correctly, it will work.

Comment: @PulsatingAmbience: What they are, for one.

Comment: @PulsatingAmbience: No, I am a 77k SO user with a C++ gold badge and 2,438 answers under my belt, not to mention _years_ of C++ experience in a competitive commercial field, so I have no idea what a local variable is.

Comment: Alright kids, maybe go to the chat room? Some of us have to work, you know :-)

Comment: @PulsatingAmbience Well, he is so-beauty.

Comment: @juanchopanza: What is "_the_ chat room"?

Comment: We need to clean up the topic of our off-topic stuff. I'll be the first

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `return CurrentValue;` reads `CurrentValue` outside the protection of the mutex. That means another thread may be writing to it "at the same time". That is a data race, and therefore undefined behaviour.

In any case, the code should be written properly with RAII, and the problem won't even be worth thinking about.

```
int Class::NextValue()
{
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
   ++CurrentValue;
   ++CurrentValue;
   return CurrentValue;
}
```

Comment: But `return localValue;` reads `localValue` outside the protection too? This is the same as with `return CurrentValue;` ?

Comment: `localValue` is not shared because it's a local variable. Nothing else can even see it, much less write to it.

Comment: `localValue` is local for mutex, function or thread? Because in case local in function there is only one `localValue` in memory?

Comment: It's a local variable. If you don't know what that is yet, you should not be messing with concurrent code.

Comment: The basic problem is that the OP did not uderstand what a thread is: 'It means there are separate call Stack for each thread?'.

Comment: @PulsatingAmbience what's with the attitude? Have you considered that these people are trying to *help* answer your question?